# Get Value From Attribute in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this attribute element and I want to extract the value from it.
I'm not sure how will I do it?
I want to extract value from

```
<select name="Hello/1.0/TestWorld" size="1" disabled="disabled" data-original-title="" title="">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="Hello">Hello</option>
 </select>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  const hello = $('qualifier="Hello/1.0/TestWorld"')

  console.log('HELLO', hello)
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @evolutionxbox. I did try your edited comment. That's the result of the error

Comment: Is the `element` attribute interpreted by a HTML pre-processor that you're using? It's not a standard HTML element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  const elem = jQuery('[name="Hello/1.0/TestWorld"]');

  console.log(`HELLO: "${elem.val()}"`)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="Hello/1.0/TestWorld" size="1" disabled="disabled" data-original-title="" title="">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="Hello">Hello</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: Sorry. I updated my question `select`

Comment: Updated my answer. It outputs an empty string but that's because the dropdown item selected has `value=""` so an empty string really is the value of the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

You can access it like this (referred to your original request):

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="helloDiv">
        <attribute qualifier="Hello/1.0/TestWorld" editable="false"></attribute>
    </div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            const hello = $('.helloDiv attribute');

            console.log('HELLO ', hello.attr('qualifier'), hello.attr('editable'));
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```